# Select value of an element property with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to extract a value of span tag property using selenium.
This is the html code :

```
<small class="time">
  <a title="2015" class="class2 class3 class4 class5" href="url">
    <span data-long-form="true" data-time-ms="1438835437000" data-time="1438835437" data-aria-label-part="last" class="class6 class7">Aug 5</span>
  </a>
</small>
```

I need to extract the value of the "date-time" property of the span tag, here is the python code I am trying to use :

```
try:
    timestamp = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//small[contains(@class, 'time')]/a[1]/span[1]")
    print "timestamp", timestamp.value_of_css_property("data-time")
except exp.NoSuchElementException:
       print "Timestamp location not proper"
```

I also tried :

```
timestamp = element.find_element_by_css_selector(".class2.class3.class4.class5").value_of_css_property("date-time")
```

but all are returning blank result.

Any Idea what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: When you post HTML in the future, please take a minute to format it properly in a tool like http://jsbeautifier.org/, etc. It makes it MUCH easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_attribute()`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("small.time span[data-time]")
element.get_attribute("data-time")
```

Note that in your second attempt, you've used `date-time` instead of `data-time`.

Comment: That works great, I perfectly got the result I need, thanks